# Motifs Size 3 versus Triad Census

Tags: igraph

By running these two lines over the same directed network:

```
triads18 <- triad.census(pax)
motifs18 <- graph.motifs(pax,3)
```

I get two lists, 16 rows each, but the counts of 3-node sub-graphs are different, overlapping in a random manner. How is that possible? I understand that motifs may be listed under 13 subclasses in a slightly different order, but then why 16 rows?

triads18

```
1   73764039
2   75340091
3   7396423
4   258648
5   32988
6   68612
7   345
8   2509
9   672
10  3
11  2
12  24
13  88
14  6
15  3
16  0
```

motifs18

```
1   NA
2   NA
3   32988
4   NA
5   68612
6   345
7   258648
8   672
9   24
10  2509
11  2
12  3
13  6
14  88
15  3
16  0
```

Answer (score 1):

this was helpful. still need to understand the differences, but at least could plot the motifs to know which is which:
https://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/igraph-help/2010-02/msg00035.html